# What is wrong with my javascript function? (XMLHttpRequest)

Tags: javascript, php, xmlhttprequest

So, this is my function to send email, but its not posting correctly...It runs, loads the file .php, returns the data and display it on the status's div, but the POSTs are empty. What is wrong? I'm pasting this at the bottom of the page, after the jquery call.

What am I doing wrong?

```
function sendemail(){

var name = document.getElementById('name').value;
var email = document.getElementById('email').value;
var subject = document.getElementById('subject').value;
var msg = document.getElementById('message').value;
var status = document.getElementById('status').value;
var hr = new XMLHttpRequest();
var url = "send-email.php";
var vars ="name="+name+"&email="+email+"&subject="+subject+"&msg="+msg+"&status="+status;
hr.open("POST", url, true);
hr.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
hr.onreadystatechange = function() {
  if(hr.readyState == 4 && hr.status == 200) {
    var return_data = hr.responseText;
    document.getElementById("status").innerHTML = return_data;
    }
  }
hr.send(vars);
setTimeout(function () {
  hr.send(vars);
}, 500);
document.getElementById('status').innerHTML = "Sending...";

}
```

Thanks.

Comment: What do you get when you var_dump $_POST?

Comment: Why are you sending the variables twice? Get rid of the one with the timeout.

Comment: Sorry, I was trying to see if placing the code above would work, you can exclude that from the real code.

Comment: I am getting nothing from dumping the $_POST (array(0) { })

Comment: The problem was that the file I was trying to open was in a folder inside another folder. Once I moved the file to a "closer" folder, it started to work.